# To solve this extra window bug in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, bug, ui

I have got this kind of glossy window on top of other windows regularly in OSX Yosemite 10.10.2, two times per month approximately. 
You cannot press anything there. 
It blocks the user interface completely. 
To restart the system fixes the problem temporarily. 
The window stays there although you switch a program.

[image]

I do not understand the cause of it, but I have produced it in Macbook Air 2013-mid and the newest Macbook Air so probably the problem is in the software.

I do not know if some programs can interact for this bug. 
Used applications at the time of appearance of such a bug

- Preview
- Texpad
- Microsoft Outlook 2013
- Google Chrome
- Finder
- sometimes Terminal
- Mail passively open sometimes
- Dropbox (in continuous overflow, never managing perfect syncing)
- BitTorrent Sync (however, this bug appeared much before this program so not causing the problem)

**How can you solve this bug in Yosemite?**

Comment: I've removed the image of the bug report from the statement of the problem. That's best presented on this site in the "answer" section. Thanks for being patient as we work out the details. Cheers! I've reproduced this issue on 10.10.3 but didn't grab a screen shot. I'll file a second radar once I have "proof" of the corruption.

Answer (score 1):

I filled a bug report to Apple to solve this buffer corruption problem, made [here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html). The only workaround is to log out of the Mac and then log back in. That typically clears the graphics frame buffers. If not, a reboot will recover from the failure, but not prevent it from happening again.

[image]

Comment: This isn't really an answer - you should add the relevant details to you original question; probably excluding the picture as it gives no new information.

Comment: @patrix Let's the admin decide. Last time, he encouraged me to include bug reports to answers, not to body of question. Bug report is a description of the situation i.e. an attempt to solve the problem. You cannot solve this bug alone. So I think this report is better for an answer. So I disagree with Tetsujin.

Comment: I'm probably to blame. I see an answer saying unequivocally that something is a bug and is/was/should be reported to Apple a good thing. I personally file these bug reports with http://openradar.appspot.com and link here to the wording, but even with the large screen shot intstead of text - +1 from me for this bug report and proactive communication.

Comment: @Masi Please log bugs with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com. This feeds into the "radar" system that Apple use for bug tracking. Apple staff can communicate back and forth there with you about the bugs you find. I've had success getting bugs fixed through that site. Make sure to provide as much information as possible in the bug that you log though; I'm not sure how seriously they would take a URL pointing to a question here.